# Вопрос по терминологии Java

Tags: java, терминология, перевод, русификация

У Шилдта заметил такое понятие как "область действия". Судя по тексту это то же самое что и "область видимости". Есть ли разница между этими терминами, или все это происки надмозгов?

> Во многих языках программирования поддерживаются две общие категории
>   областей действия: глобальная и локальная.

Шилдт Герберт - Java: руководство для начинающих

Comment: Нужен контекст. Приведите полную цитату

Comment: Я бы лично вообще бы запретил публиковать книжки Шилдта - это же просто шарлатан, я помню в детстве были его книжки типа: *Basic/Pascal: руководство/библия для начинающих/профессионалов* - вот он навсегда остался там, не надо ему писать ни про C++/Java - не его это.

Comment: Действие не предполагает видимость? Или наоборот. Я бы даже не заострял внимание на этом.

Comment: @Barmaley а ещё большую часть переводчиков расстрелять нужно :)

Comment: правильно, поэтому я читаю в оригинале (хорошо, что у прогеров английский это язык общения - как латынь у медиков)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Герберт Шилдт. Java 8: руководство для начинающих. 6-е издание (стр. 69, раздел "Область действия и время жизни переменных"):

> Как пояснялось в главе l, блок начинается с открывающей фигурной скобки и оканчивается закрывающей фигурной скобкой. Блок определяет ***область действия* (видимости)** переменных. Начиная новый блок, вы всякий раз создаете новую область действия.

Herbert Schildt. Java. The complete reference. Ninth edition. (стр. 45, раздел "The Scope and Lifetime of Variables"):

> As explained in Chapter 2, a block is begun with an opening curly brace and ended by a closing curly brace. A block defines a ***scope***. Thus, each time you start a new block, you are creating a new scope.

То, что в оригинале описывается одним словом *scope*, перевели двумя разными словосочетаниями *область видимости* и *область действия*. В общем понятно, что это одно и то же.